# How to change button's background in XML Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a problem, i can't change the background of my button

This is my button :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/gLineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/gLineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword"/>
```

And this is my background in drawable/btn_bg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:color="@color/login_form_details" android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke android:color="@color/login_form_details_light" android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This is the result :
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUlXP.png)

The color is always in "colorPrimary"

Did I make a mistake ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: try `app:background` instead of `android:background`

Comment: If Zain's solution doesn't work, try adding ```app:backgroundTint="@null"``` alongside ```android:background```

Comment: ```app:background``` doesn't work, but ```app:backgroundTint="@null"``` work !
Thank you guys !